# Store unicode codepoint in varchar(SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ascii, extended-ascii

When I create the following table in **SQL Server (2016)**

`create table test100(Id int not null primary key identity, str1 varchar(100))`

And then insert following data :

`insert into test100(str1) values(nchar(1610))`

The character "ی" is recorded in the table, That is, the Unicode character was stored in the ascii field :

```
select substring(str1,1,1),
      ascii(substring(str1,1,1)),
      unicode(substring(str1,1,1)),
      DATALENGTH(str1),
from test100
```

Why is the Unicode character stored in ascii field?

Database collation : SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS

Comment: What collation is your database?

Comment: The Unicode character is not stored. The actual character stored will depend on your column collation, which may or may not properly map the Unicode character to the proper code point depending on the collation code page.

Comment: Because [cp1256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256) supports a limited number of Arabic script characters. U+064A, ي, gets stored as the byte 0xED.

Comment: Seemingly, you should use nvarchar data type instead of varchar for the column "str1" with the collation.